# Python CSV Reader wont print rows correctly

Tags: python, csv

I am reading a csv file and taking a row in the csv file and putting it into a list.

```
    with open('DADSA 2019-20 CWK A DATA PETS.csv', 'r') as petData:
  petData = csv.DictReader(petData)
  data = {}
  for row in petData:
    for header, value in row.items():
      try:
        data[header].append(value)
      except KeyError:
        data[header] = [value]
animalType = data['Type']    
breed = data['Breed']    
vacine = data['Vaccinated']    
neuter= data['Neutered']    
admissionReason = data['Reason for admission']            
arrivalDate = data['Date of Arrival']
destination = data ['Destination '],['Sanctuary Identification']
destinationAdd = data ['Destination Address']
```

when I print "animalType" This appears:

> ['Cat', 'Cat', 'Dog', 'Parrot', 'Cat', 'Cat', 'Dog', 'Dog', 'Canary', 'Dog', 'Dog', 'Cat', 'Cat', 'Cat', 'Parrot', 'Parrot', 'Dog', 'Cat', 'Cat', 'Cat', 'Dog', 'Dog', 'Dog', 'Canary', 'Cat', 'Dog', 'Dog', 'Cat', 'Cat', 'Cat']

which is perfect. However when I start to implement a loop it gets messed up.

```
if option =="4":
for item in animalType:
    if item == "Dog":
        print(row)
```

which gives this output:

> ['P11456', 'Cat', 'Persian', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'D234567', 'Lost', '11/09/2019', '11/10/2019', 'return to owner', '333 New Lane, SE14 6RT']
>   ['P12467', 'Cat', 'Ancora', 'Yes', '', 'D123456', 'Lost', '14/09/2019', '30/09/2019', 'return to owner', '290 Oak Avenue, BS79 8TR']
>   ['P31222', 'Dog', 'Alsatian', 'Yes', '', 'D220956', 'Lost', '24/09/2019', '10/10/2019', 'return to owner', '25 Newtown Road, NT56 6YU']
>   ['P24119', 'Cat', 'Himalayan', 'Yes', '', 'D189875', 'Lost', '26/09/2019', '17/10/2019', 'return to owner', '43 Glynt Lane, CF76 5TR']
>   ['P25311', 'Dog', 'Dachshund', 'Yes', '', 'D221133', 'Lost', '28/09/2019', '12/10/2019', 'return to owner', '23 Lonely Court, BS1 1TY']
>   ['P25412', 'Cat', 'Ragdoll', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'D101033', 'Lost', '28/09/2019', '12/10/2019', 'return to owner', '29 Lonely Court, BS1 1TY']
>   ['P25634', 'Cat', 'Ragdoll', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'D222111', 'Stray', '29/09/2019', '', '', '']
>   ['P25634', 'Cat', 'Ragdoll', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'D222111', 'Stray', '29/09/2019', '', '', '']
>   ['P25634', 'Cat', 'Ragdoll', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'D222111', 'Stray', '29/09/2019', '', '', '']
>   ['P25634', 'Cat', 'Ragdoll', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'D222111', 'Stray', '29/09/2019', '', '', '']
>   ['P25634', 'Cat', 'Ragdoll', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'D222111', 'Stray', '29/09/2019', '', '', '']
>   ['P25634', 'Cat', 'Ragdoll', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'D222111', 'Stray', '29/09/2019', '', '', '']
>   ['P25634', 'Cat', 'Ragdoll', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'D222111', 'Stray', '29/09/2019', '', '', '']
>   ['P25634', 'Cat', 'Ragdoll', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'D222111', 'Stray', '29/09/2019', '', '', '']
>   ['P25634', 'Cat', 'Ragdoll', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'D222111', 'Stray', '29/09/2019', '', '', '']
>   ['P25634', 'Cat', 'Ragdoll', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'D222111', 'Stray', '29/09/2019', '', '', '']
>   ['P25634', 'Cat', 'Ragdoll', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'D222111', 'Stray', '29/09/2019', '', '', '']

It is also printing the rows of cats.

I want the code to check through the CSV files second row (which I have called animalType) and if in that column their is a "Dog", I want it to print that row.

Is my method just wrong or do I have the right idea and bad execution?

EDIT:

I have now changed the code and I am getting a different issue

```
if option =="4":
    with open('DADSA 2019-20 CWK A DATA PETS.csv', 'r') as petData:
        petData = csv.DictReader(petData)
        data = {}
        for row in petData:
            if row['Type'] == "Dog" and row['Vaccinated'] == "Yes" and row['Microchip Number'] != 0 and row ['Neutered'] == "Yes":
                Dogs.append(row)
                print(Dogs)
```

the output is this:

> []
>   ['P11456', 'Cat', 'Persian', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'D234567', 'Lost', '11/09/2019', '11/10/2019', 'return to owner', '333 New Lane, SE14 6RT']
>   ['P12467', 'Cat', 'Ancora', 'Yes', '', 'D123456', 'Lost', '14/09/2019', '30/09/2019', 'return to owner', '290 Oak Avenue, BS79 8TR']
>   ['P31222', 'Dog', 'Alsatian', 'Yes', '', 'D220956', 'Lost', '24/09/2019', '10/10/2019', 'return to owner', '25 Newtown Road, NT56 6YU']
>   ['P24119', 'Cat', 'Himalayan', 'Yes', '', 'D189875', 'Lost', '26/09/2019', '17/10/2019', 'return to owner', '43 Glynt Lane, CF76 5TR']
>   ['P25311', 'Dog', 'Dachshund', 'Yes', '', 'D221133', 'Lost', '28/09/2019', '12/10/2019', 'return to owner', '23 Lonely Court, BS1 1TY']
>   ['P25412', 'Cat', 'Ragdoll', 'Yes', 'Yes', 'D101033', 'Lost', '28/09/2019', '12/10/2019', 'return to owner', '29 Lonely Court, BS1 1TY']
>   [OrderedDict([('Sanctuary Identification', 'P24117'), ('Type', 'Dog'), ('Breed', 'Bulldog'), ('Vaccinated', 'Yes'), ('Neutered', 'Yes'), ('Microchip Number', 'D121323'), ('Reason for admission', 'Abandoned'), ('Date of Arrival', '26/09/2019'), ('Date of Departure', ''), ('Destination ', ''), ('Destination Address', '')])]
>   [OrderedDict([('Sanctuary Identification', 'P24117'), ('Type', 'Dog'), ('Breed', 'Bulldog'), ('Vaccinated', 'Yes'), ('Neutered', 'Yes'), ('Microchip Number', 'D121323'), ('Reason for admission', 'Abandoned'), ('Date of Arrival', '26/09/2019'), ('Date of Departure', ''), ('Destination ', ''), ('Destination Address', '')]), OrderedDict([('Sanctuary Identification', 'P24142'), ('Type', 'Dog'), ('Breed', 'Bulldog'), ('Vaccinated', 'Yes'), ('Neutered', 'Yes'), ('Microchip Number', 'D223311'), ('Reason for admission', 'Abused'), ('Date of Arrival', '28/09/2019'), ('Date of Departure', ''), ('Destination ', ''), ('Destination Address', '')])]

as you can see, the beginning of the output is wrong, it is displaying cats for no reason. However, the end part of the output is displaying the 3 correct rows.

Comment: Please paste the complete code that results the output shown.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just do this:

```
for row in petData:
    if row['Type'] == "Dog":
        print(row)
```

Rather than splitting out every attribute into separate lists?

Comment: Because my teacher said I get more marks by splitting everything off into separate lists.

Comment: Also it still does the same thing, still prints random info I don't want

Comment: Please provide the csv file and your full requirements in the question - otherwise it is very hard to give you help.

Comment: I have edited my question with code and output now modified based on your recommendation

Comment: Please post your entire code. There is no reason that the current code should not work.